# ArrayAdapter from ArrayList showing resource ID not value

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am attempting to populate a spinner from a ArrayList.

The issue I have is that instead of displaying the values in the ArrayList, the spinner is showing the full path to the resource id instead!

my code

```
@Override
public void CartonMoveOptions(ArrayList<BarcodeSpinner> bSpinner) {
    Spinner BarcodeChoice = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cartonChoices);
    BarcodeChoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ArrayAdapter<BarcodeSpinner> a = new ArrayAdapter<BarcodeSpinner>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bSpinner);
    a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    BarcodeChoice.setAdapter(a);
}
```

BarcodeSpinner contains two lines, and the only content is a single string for each line.

Can anyone point out what is wrong?

This is my BarcodeSpinner class

```
public class BarcodeSpinner {

    String Barcode;

    public String getBarcode() {
        return Barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        Barcode = barcode;
    }
}
```

ANSWER:

Add

```
@Override
Public String toString()
{
return Barcode;
}
```

to BarcodeSpinner

Comment: Your problem presumably lies in whatever `toString()` is returning in `BarcodeSpinner`.

Comment: `the full path to the resource id` what do you mean? (I guess you need to override ArrayAdapter to populate the view with the elements from BarcodeSpinner that you actually need. what you are seeing is probably the default toString implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `ArrayAdapter`, will invoke the `toString` method of the object you provide in the dataset. The easy fix would be to override this `toString` in your `BarcodeSpinner` class, making it return the string you want to show